# setfenv with require function in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm using Lua 5.1 and I want to sandbox some files. `setfenv` with `loadfile` seems work, but I want to use `require` as well because I want to use mechanism provided by `require`. I have some custom loaders to load file that isn't located on disk. Is it possible? Or is there any alternative solution?

Comment: I've written a [Lua module](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-modjail) that isolates all modules from each other as much as possible. I don't use it anymore myself, but perhaps you'll find it interesting ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here would seem to be pretty obvious: have the file you `require` not be the file that implements the module. Instead, have the `require`d file `loadfile` and sandbox the actual module. It can then return that module.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it, how does this solution work? To load actual module, `require`d file have to call `require`, again. Whatever, I would like to keep modules unconscious of being sandboxed.

Comment: @Noverull: That's why I said you "load" the actual module. You don't use `require` on it; you use `loadfile` on it. Modules are not special; they're just Lua scripts.

Comment: It breaks the use of `require`. I have some files that can't be loaded by `loadfile`.

Comment: @Noverull: How do you write a Lua script that cannot be loaded by `loadfile`? And if it's a DLL, you *cannot* sandbox a DLL.

Comment: for example, encrypted lua script or lua script in compressed archieve.

Comment: @Noverull: `require` wouldn't be able to call them either. At least, not unless you extended `require` with the ability to decrpyt/decompress the script. Which would mean that you would have some equivalent to the `loadfile` which is capable of loading a Lua script into Lua without executing it. In which case, feel free to substitute that function for `loadfile` in this case.